# How to create specific chain of numbers

Tags: javascript, function

I have a school prompt to create a function that finds out which integer, in the range that the user enters, produces the longest chain. The "chain" consists of:

- Ask user for a number.
- If the number is even, divide by 2.
- If it's odd multiply by 3 and add 1.
- Continue this until you reach 1.

E.g. if you start with 3, the sequence will be 3-10-5-16-8-4-2-1. The function will print out the number that produces the longest chain and the actual integers in that chain (length of the chain).

This is what I have so far. I can't figure it out.

```
function chain2()
        var startNumber = prompt("Enter starting number of range", "4");
        var endNumber = prompt ("Enter ending number of range", "9")

        var separator="-";
        while (currentNumber>1){
            if (currentNumber%2==1){
                currentNumber=currentNumber*3+1;
                chain+=separator+currentNumber;
            }
            else if (currentNumber%2==0){
                currentNumber=currentNumber/2;
                chain+=separator+currentNumber;
            }

        }
        return chain;
        }
        document.write(chain());
```

Comment: What if you never reach 1? AFAIK the Collatz conjecture has not been proven.

Comment: i don't know my teacher never mentioned that. she just wants us to find the longest chain and print it somehow

Comment: You need to add `var chain = "";` before your loop, so that `chain` is an empty string that you can add to. Where does `currentNumber` come from? You're not currently prompting for it. (Also, although it's doing no particular harm, you don't need the `else if` condition, you can just use a plain `else`.)

Comment: @Oriol The conjecture has been checked by computer for all starting values up to 2^60. If somebody uses this application to disprove the conjecture, that would be a nice problem to have :-)

Answer (score 1):

As a homework assignment, I should nudge you rather than just give you the answer. If there's a single point of advice I would give you, it's that you should separate your work into easy-to-understand functions first. Writing one big function that does everything is a recipe for a disaster. The function you have right now

- gives two prompts for user input
- loops based on the user inputs
- determines even and odd values
- performs basic arithmetic according to the Collatz chain procedure

Breaking this into separate parts will make it much easier to reason about your code. I start from the top-level function that I wish would work, and then work my way down from there.

```
function FindMaxCollatzInRange(x,y) {
  // max = ...
  // ...
  return max;
}
```

If you find yourself needing other functions, that's perfectly normal. Write them as you need them.

Your basic algorithm should do something like this:

- for numbers between `min` and `max` (inclusive) ...
- compute and record the collatz chain length for each number
- based on the recorded lengths, return the number with the highest length

---

> So here's how I would do this. This is way beyond the scope of a JavaScript homework assignment, but I found it fun to work on.
>
> I'm OK posting this code because I know it can't directly be copy/pasted as an answer for your assignment. My hope is that there will be some things here that will encourage you to explore some of the techniques used.

```
// compute the collatz chain for a given number, x
const collatz = Y (f=> y=> x=> {
  if (x === 1)   return append (x) (y);
  if (isEven(x)) return f (append (x) (y)) (x/2);
  else           return f (append (x) (y)) (x*3 + 1);
}) ([]);

// compute the length of a collatz chain
const collatzLen = comp (len) (collatz);

// create a range from minimum, n, to maximum, m
const range = Y (f=> r=> n=> m=> {
  if (n > m)  return r;
  else        return f (append (n) (r)) (n+1) (m);
}) ([]);

// compute the maximum collatz chain length for a given range
const maxCollatz = (n,m) =>
  comp (foldl (([x,xlen])=> ([y,ylen])=> ylen > xlen ? [y,ylen] : [x,xlen]) ([0,1]))
       (map (n=> [n,collatzLen (n)]))
       (range (n) (m));
```

Here's some sample output of the functions so you can see what's going on

```
collatz (3)
//=> [ 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 ]

collatzLen (3)
//=> 8

range (3) (10)
//=> [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]

maxCollatz (3,10)
//=> [ 9, 20 ]
```

The way to read that last output `[ 9, 20 ]` is, "The number 9 has the longest Collatz chain length, with a length of 20"

Simply put, each function is responsible for doing exactly *one* thing. The function that answers your problem is the `maxCollatz` function, which computes a list of chain lengths using `collatzLen` for each element in the `range`. Lastly, the list is reduced to determine which number has the longest chain.

Here are the generic dependencies

```
const comp = f=> g=> x=> f (g (x));
const mod = x=> y=> y % x;
const eq = x=> y=> y === x;
const isEven = comp (eq (0)) (mod (2));
const prop = x=> y=> y [x];
const len = prop ('length');
const concat = x=> xs=> xs .concat (x);
const append = x=> concat ([x]);
const foldl = f=> y=> xs=> xs .reduce ((x,y)=> f (x) (y), y);
const map = f=> xs=> xs .map (x=> f(x));

// U-combinator
const U = f=> f (f);

// Y-combinator
const Y = U (h=> f=> f (x=> h (h) (f) (x)));
```

Additional reading:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)

Comment: Wow. Way to overcomplicate a problem that can easily be done in one function of a dozen lines. The OP's code is 75% there as is. (I do agree with the principal of writing smaller functions that only do one thing, but for this problem really a single function that accepts the upper and lower bounds as arguments would be perfectly fine when called with the user input.)

Comment: kek, the answer explicitly says I'm not going to answer it for him/her. Code is only provided because I know it cannot be plagiarised for their homework submission and it answers the original question of "how to create a specific chain of numbers?" which may be useful to other readers. As I said, it was a fun problem to work on and the code here offers many techniques to explore.

Comment: And while this specific problem could be solve "in one function of a dozen lines" when learning it's always a good thing to explore better techniques and understanding how something more advanced could be solved. For a school assignment it's never about solving the problem in the fewest number of chars it's about learning and solving the problem in a way that you learn. Promoting bad solutions to people trying to learn is wasteful and just creates more and more bad coders instead of helping them become good.

Comment: @stenehall - I'm not promoting a bad solution, because solving a simple problem with a simple, short function is *not* a bad thing. Breaking problems up into smaller pieces is a good idea, but this answer goes so far beyond that that "overkill" doesn't even apply. The code shown here is quite difficult to read with all the one- and two-letter variable names that give little clue as to what they're for - that's not something that others should be encouraged to emulate.

Comment: When a function body is only an expression or two, it's very plain to see how each parameter contributes to the computation. Do you prefer `function add (addend) { return function (augend) { var sum = addend + augend; return sum; }}` over `const add = x=> y=> y + x` ? Does the added verbosity and word-like variables help you understand that computation better? "That's not something that others should be encouraged to emulate"? Haskell and Lambda Calculus are without their merits then, right? Not to mention other languages like Scheme and Racket where I see similar styles used...

Comment: The paradigm and style might be foreign to you, but that doesn't mean you should discourage it without warrant. I could just as easily point out flaws of imperative style, but for sake of keeping things constructive, I refrained from doing so.

Comment: Sorry, no, examples like your `add`, `prop`, and `concat` are quite clear the way you do it. Something like `Y = U (h=> f=> f (x=> h (h) (f) (x)));` would be easier to understand with longer names, especially given that you posted it specifically to help people learn.

Comment: Sorry to double-comment, but since my previous one I thought a bit more about what you said about keeping things constructive. I wasn't arguing for the sake of arguing, but if you think my previous comments are unhelpful I'm happy to delete them (let me know). In the meantime, instead of my previous "that is overkill", may I start again more constructively by saying "would you mind explaining the benefit of introducing several levels of currying for isEven rather than `x => x % 2 === 0`".

Comment: `Y = U (h=> f=> f (x=> h (h) (f) (x)))` is the well-known [Y-combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus) in the functional programming world.  It's my fault for not documenting that more specifically.

Comment: As for `isEven`, the reasoning is two fold. 1) it *is* a composition of two computations; equality and modulo. Equality and modulo do not exist as functions in JavaScript, (instead as operators), therefore they cannot be composed. 2) It is largely impractical to compose functions of more than 1 argument, hence the preference of currying everything. If everything exists as unary (1 parameter) functions, they can all be composed (or "piped" together) with trivial effort.

Comment: One last remark I will make about `x => x % 2 === 0` is, notice that my definition doesn't even involve the term, `x`. It can be said that my definition is [point-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming). This isn't meant to sound like bragging, rather the definition has a lesser cognitive load on the reader. Having to only focus on the sequence of `eq(0)` and `mod(2)` without worrying about a variable binding (`x`) again pulls the very specific "nature" of `isEven` closer to the surface.

Comment: And thank you for helping me recalibrate the discussion toward a constructive one. There's no need to delete previous comments. JavaScript is a multi-paradigm language so it has becoming a melting pot of all sorts of styles and opinions. There's many ways to solve each problem and each of them have pros and cons. Imperative style just happens to be the style taught to most beginners but it is no more (or less) "correct" than other styles such as object-oriented or functional.

Comment: Thanks for the response.